# index usage on union where conditions

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-5.5

I have a following query:

```
select *
from t
where t.a = '1' or t.b = '2' or t.c = '3'
```

full scan is performed as there is no single index that will satisy these conditions.

Are there any way to avoid full scans and use indexes?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html), MySQL does offer an "index merge".  However, I'm not sure it actually gets used much in practice.

First, let me assume that you have indexes on `t(a)`, `t(b)`, and `t(c)`.  Then, check if the index merge helps.

If not, rephrase the query as a `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) query:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.a = '1' 
union
select t.*
from t
where t.b = '2' 
union
select t.*
from t
where t.c = '3';
```

Each of the subqueries should use an index.  The `UNION` does incur overhead for removing duplicates.  If you *know* there are no duplicates (or do not care about them), then change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score -1):

Why not creating a complex index over the 3 columns in you where?

You can create INDEX(a, b, c) see ref: [MySQL Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: that will help only intersecting queries, such as `t.a = '1' and t.b = '2' and t.c='3'`

Comment: You are right, if you plan to create a dynamic query, that columns on the where clause will change (but the select is the same) then it not the solution for you, and I'll suggest using the UNION solution.
But. if the where clause on your query will always be t.a = ? OR t.b = ? OR .. Then it will work for you,and the query will run faster and will be cleaner.